# Any way to inject dependecies into controller with silent error in case no matched provider found out

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Is there any way to do the following case using annotation style injection with no provider exception just null references.

```
angular.module('test',[]).controller('cont',['NonExixstingService',function(nonExixstingService){
   //I want to be get here with no exception but NonExixstingService is null or undefined
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, But I can think of a workaround which could be used with ngRoute or ui.router.

On your state or route set the resolve property like:

```
resolve : { 
    serviceName:[$q,$injector,function($q,$injector){
        var exists = $injector.has('serviceName');
        return $q.resolve(exists ? $injector.get('serviceName') : null)
    }]
};
```

Not sure how this would react the local name being the same as a service name so you might have to alias the service. The resolve property will inject its values into the controller its keys will be the local variable name.

But if you're going to go through that trouble, You should just inject the $injector, and perform the `.has` check inside your controller